# SQL QUERY using WHERE from ANOTHER TABLE

Tags: sql

I'd like to ask some help from you guys please regarding this sql query across another table.

Sample Table A

| cid | migratable | status | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | completed | aaa. |
| 2 | TRUE | ongoing | b. |
| 3 | FALSE | completed | bbb. |
| 4 | TRUE | completed |  |

Sample Table B

| cid | activity_type | assmnt_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | migrate | completed |
| 2 |  | ongoing |
| 3 | migrate |  |
| 4 | sip | completed |

1. I need to count "true"  values under Table A column migratable, where **data** is equal to **blank** and **activity_type from Table B is not equal to blank**, then **assmnt_status from Table B is equal to Completed**
2. I need to count "false"  values under Table A column migratable, where migratable is equal to false and
   **data** is equal to **blank** and **activity_type from Table B is not equal to blank**, then **assmnt_status from Table B is equal to Completed**

Comment: You need to do a join between the tables and then you can do a where on the joined tables.  You'd get more help if you stated what SQL you're using, ie mssql/mysql/etc.  It's also not super clear what your table structure.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Apology i dont know hot create table in stakcoverflow i tried to edit through excel but it is in one line

Comment: Please show expected result set sample also

Comment: Is "blank" an empty string or `null`? They require different syntax to check!

Comment: Yes its a null value

Comment: Checking for nulls is `column IS NULL` or `column IS NOT NULL` - note the `IS` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple join assuming cid column is the identifier column. The query can be something like below, you didn't post the column data types and column description, you may need to customize the sql a little bit further based on your data types and table/index design.

@ER Sy I saw you edited your questions and conditions(blank in your table meant null value) afterwards, in that case, the query needs to be modified based on your new input.

```
select a.migratable, count(*) 
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.cid = b.cid 
where a.data IS NULL 
  and b.activity_type IS NOT NULL 
  and b.assmnt_status = 'completed' 
group by a.migratable
```

Comment: Please go for ANSI join syntax. It is more clear

Comment: But i need to count also the false? in one table only. :( how to do it?

Comment: @ERSy - your question didn't specify that! But you would need to add a `GROUP BY a.migratable` and remove the where-filter for that column. And add that column to the select-list